# Column wider on first page of SSRS report than on other pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a column in a tablix on an SSRS report that is printing wider on the first page, but then the size I want it to be on the following pages.  Any suggestions?

Pictures below showing first page, second page, and design.

[image: Tablix Design]

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 0):

On the Properties Pane. Look for the property **"CanGrow"** and **"CanShrink"**. Make their value FALSE

Comment: They are currently set to that.  I have even tried all combinations of those two properties and the error persists.